# Finding an optimal number of different containers that can be made of the required amount

Tags: optimization, algorithms

For example, `35ml` needed where only `16ml` and `10ml` available. 35ml can be made with `(3pcs of 16ml) = 48, (4pcs x 10ml) = 40 or (1 x 16ml, 2 x 10ml) =` 36 but the optimal one is `(1 x 16ml, 2 x 10ml)` because there is only `1 = 36-35` space unlike others.

**Update:**

I was trying to use linear programming which may help to find x and/or y (finding the quantity) based on constraints but it's like I find it difficult to implement.

Constraints are:

```
Let z be the number of space
X and/or Y to be the quantity
16x + 10y >= 35
x>=0
y>=0

outcome = 16(1) + 10(2) >= 35
```

Comment: In general, I think you are asking for [Integer linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming)

Answer (score 0):

Let z be the excess

and x and y be the number of 16ml and 10ml bottles.  So they are defined as integers

Let A be the desired Amount. So the optimization problem is

$Min$   $ z= 16x + 10y - A$
such that
$x,y,z \ge 0$

$x,y$ are integers

[image]

[image]

[image]